# Username change only changes numbers, not text

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that users can use to change their username, but it only works for numbers!

The username type is set to VARCHAR, I can manually set a text username and when registering, the entry can be text using the INSERT INTO code.

Here's the form

```
<html>
<center><h2>Username Change</h2></center>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="">
 <input type="text" name="something" value="<?= isset($_POST['something']) ?    ($_POST['something']) : '' ?>" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" />
 </form>
```

And here's the code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $newname = $_POST['something'];
    $change = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET users.username = $newname WHERE    users.id=$id4");
    }
```

Don't know where I'm going wrong!

Comment: You realise that strings should be quoted in SQL..... but as you're using MySQLi, switch to using prepared statements and bind variables.... then you don't need to remember to quote strings or escape your values, so you're protecting yourself against SQL injection as well

Comment: Jesus christ I always miss the stupid things!! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
    $change = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET users.username = '$newname' WHERE    users.id=$id4");
```

Comment: There's a blatant sql injection problem. It solves the problem, but solves it badly!